# Sharing layout between multiple apps

Tags: android, module, android-library

### Problem

I have multiple **apps** that have the **same** exact **layout** and **functionality**. Think of it as: creating same app for multiple pizza restaurants.

Now I need to make an android module that will just extract everything(**activities, layout, code, etc..**) to these apps without the need to **manually** create **activities** and then call the xml that is in my module.

---

### Steps I've done

I followed the module tutorial on [Google's Android site here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#Convert). Specifically,

1. Convert an app module to a library module
2. Generated the AAR file
3. Add the library as a dependency

---

### Details

The previous steps work, however, I will have to create all **activity** in each **single** **project**, then modify the `setContent()` to call my library xml `setContent(R.layout.**myModule)`

- How would I go about if I want to make the module copies activities
  and layout xml to another project without the need to **manually** creating them ?
- Is there a better approach than using a module ?

Comment: You need to make a template for that and add it in android studio's template folder

Comment: What you are describing should work without any issues. Why cant you just use startActivity to start activity from your library?

Comment: @Okas, damn, thank you for this. I searched a lot and all the topics/questions never went beyond the import module step. So basically, create an intent inside my mainActivity that calls the mainActivity of my module ? Can you make this an answer so I can mark it ? off-topic: it seems the app is crashing because of twitter sdk in my module, `Didn't find class "com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterConfig$Builder"` would you know if this is because I added the sdk in my module's gradle instead of my current app ?

Comment: It is probably better to ask a new question about your TwitterConfig issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start your library activity with startActivity, no copies needed.

Comment: I created a new question related to your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353701/launching-mainactivity-found-inside-my-module-library-works-but-doesnt-load-lay