# Activity inside library module starts but doesn't display layout

Tags: android, module, android-library

### My code

**My main project**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //         --------- 0 way
               View v = new com.sohaeb.mylibrary.test(this);
    setContentView(v);

   //         --------- 1 way

    startActivity(new Intent(this, com.sohaeb.mylibrary.MainActivity.class));

   //         --------- 2nd way

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    startActivity(intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), com.sohaeb.mylibrary.MainActivity.class));

  //         --------- 3rd way
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    try {
        intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName("com.sohaeb.mylibrary.MainActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }   
 }
```

---

**My module**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "test";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: hellow ");
}
}
```

---

### **Update #2**

I have also followed this**[tutorial here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582)** which uses different approach:

```
inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this);
```

But still ended with the same problem. Class launch but no **layout**

Answer (score 2):

The solution was because I have 2 xml layouts with the same name.

i.e:

- **Main** project has `main_activity.xml`
- **Library Module** also has `main_activity.xml`.

Android will **ignore** the second one.

Hope this helps anyone.